# After running npm start command line doesn't work

Tags: github, command-line, terminal, npm-start, react-scripts

I'm hoping others have had this issue before..
I used npm start in the terminal to run my react project which opens through localhost:3000 fine, but then any following commands I write in the terminal don't execute!
I want to be able to use initialise my project through npm start, make changes in my text editor then commit the changes to GitHub through the terminal.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like the `npm start` command keeps running (which makes sense for a web server). While it's running, you can't run other commands in the same terminal – just use another terminal.

Comment: Or start it in the background: `npm start &`

Answer (score 12):

If you are using `create-react-app` `npm start` will trigger hot-reload server at `localhost:3000` and your currently opened terminal window will be running this process in the background mode. To stop it use `cmd/ctrl + c` or just simply open another terminal window to be able to install packages or do other tasks in the same folder.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses! Both bits of advice on starting a new terminal worked. I have a mac and done cmd+t which worked well! Thank you

Comment: If the answer helped, accept and upvote it please! Good luck with coding!