# VS Code code terminal loading freezes on me when I run 'npm start'

Tags: javascript, macos, visual-studio-code

When I put npm start, it freezes in the loading section, attached pic:[loading image frozen link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXyYQ.png)

For me to write in the VS code terminal, I will need to trash or kill terminal and start another one. [i have a macos]

I tried closing out the application, did not work. I reopened VS Code and it still didn't work. I installed all the necessary dependencies and the my code starts fine when I 'npm start' it, it is just the process of terminal loading that is acting up.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and it was resolved by using a different terminal after running the app using npm start.

See this answer:
Sounds like the npm start command keeps running (which makes sense for a web server). While it's running, you can't run other commands in the same terminal – just use another terminal. –
Fabian Lauer
Sep 19, 2018 at 10:21
Check out related [After running npm start command line doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52403504/after-running-npm-start-command-line-doesnt-work)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Hayes, I am the reviewer of your first anser. I think this is good enough for the asker to resolve his problem but maybe you can give him more knowledge on the root cause rather than just an instruction to overcome the problem. Try to explain why the terminal won't accept command after running `npm run start` until you stop the start command perhap.

Answer (score 0):

what's the command specified in the package.json? at the line like the one bellow. replace <COMMAND_WRITTEN_IN_HERE> with yours.

```
"scripts": {
"start": "<COMMAND_WRITTEN_IN_HERE>"
},
```